# Use php ifelse statement as $variable

Tags: php

For example if statement

```
if($number == 1){
echo '$number == 1';
}
```

Such statement need to call multiple times. And possibly latter the statement need to change.

Can place this code in external file and the use `include`.

But better would be create variable something like

```
$variable = if($number == 1){
echo '$number == 1';
}
```

This does not work. Tried with `( )`, `" "`. No success.

Any ideas? Is it possible at all?

**Updated question**

Writing one more time for those who write that question is not understandable.

So need this code `if($number == 1){ echo '$number == 1'; }` (actually code is much longer) to repeat some 30 times.

And time after time some part of code manually would need to change.

One way how can I do it is to place the code in external file, for example external_file.php and then use `require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/external_file.php");`.

Instead of including external content would want to define/create (now I see that need function).

Hope now is clear what I want.

Thanks for answers, will experiment.

Comment: Reusable code is placed in *functions*.

Comment: Please explain better.. what you want and need?

Comment: What would you do with $variable? I'm sorry, but it's not clear what you are trying to achieve here. Is it that the number 1 might vary from case to case?

Comment: @NicolasManzini please, read update.

Answer (score 1):

Please use functions for reusability

```
function reuseFun($num){
  if($num == 1){
    return 'Number = 1';
  }
  else{
    return 'Number != 1';
  }
}

echo reuseFun(1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe like this?

```
function checkNumber($number) {
  if($number == 1){
     return true;
  }
}
```

And then you can use it like this:

```
if (checkNumber(1)) {
   echo 'something';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use function :

```
function myTest($number) {
  if($number == 1){
    echo '$number == 1';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That won't work, but you could try this:

```
if($number == 1) {
    $variable = 'number is 1';
} elseif($number == 2) {
    $variable = 'number is 2';
}

echo $variable;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what you need with the if statement, however if you need shorthand form of if use following code.

```
 echo 'text '. ($number == 1 ? '$number == 1' : 'something else'). ' text';
```

[more examples](http://davidwalsh.name/php-ternary-examples)

if you need to reuse the code just put this code inside the function as follows,

```
function print_number($number){
   echo 'text '. ($number == 1 ? '$number == 1' : 'something else'). ' text';
}
```